# Replacement module for Image FUpload

Tags: 6, media, updating

Last week the [Image FUpload module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_fupload) got the "no longer supported" status because "its dependencies swfupload are not maintained and not safe anymore".

**Are there any Drupal 6 modules that can replace the Image FUpload module, allowing uploading multiple files/images at once?** An HTML5 solution would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like [ImageField Zip/HTML5 Bulk Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_zip) is doing what I need, as it allows you to select one of these upload modes: "Zip Files Only", "**HTML 5 Multi-upload Only**", "Both Zip & HTML 5". In this case I needed the second option ("HTML 5 Multi-upload Only").

Answer (score 0):

[ImageField](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield) module is the perfect solution for your requirement. It is dependent on `CCK` and `FileField` modules. Some of the additional benefits provided by `ImageField` are it works fine with AJAX upload and removal, HTML5 and you can also restrict its behavior.

Comment: But you can't use ImageField for bulk uploading, can you? I'm looking for a "one button to upload X images at once" solution.

Comment: Yes in drupal 6 it doesn't support bulk uploading. But you can try jUpload (https://www.drupal.org/project/jifupload) as extension to imagefield

Comment: It looks like [ImageField Zip/HTML5 Bulk Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_zip) is doing what I need, as it allows you to select one of these upload modes: "Zip Files Only", "**HTML 5 Multi-upload Only**", "Both Zip & HTML 5". In this case I needed the second option ("HTML 5 Multi-upload Only").

Comment: Look into imagefield configuration @user34515